# What is the combinatorial explanation of the fact that the number of all possible partial functions from set $A$ to set $B$ is $(1+n)^k$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty finite sets, $|A|=k, |B|=n$. The number of all possible partial functions from $A$ to $B$ is $(1+n)^k$. What is the combinatorial explanation for this?

I know that we can think of this problem as choosing $i$ elements of $A$ and then mapping them to $B$. This is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k {k\choose i}n^i=(1+n)^k
$$

But the sigma just happens to be equal to the binomial expansion. But why does the binomial expansion really represent the problem of counting partial functions?

Comment: Without loss of generality, let $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.  For each $a\in A$ choose which of $\{*,1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ it maps to where if it "maps to $*$" we instead reinterpret this as "it doesn't map to anything and isn't included in the function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element of $A$, there are $n+1$ options. It can not be part of the mapping, or it can be mapped to one of the $n$ elements of $B$. Since repetition is allowed, this gives a factor of $(1+n)$ for each element of $A$.